# How to make a JS menu open on hover OR on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, touch

I have a JS+CSS menu that works perfect on mouse hover, but I have to make it also work on click for touch devices.

The menu is something like this:

```
<div id="menucontainer">
  <ul id="jsddm">              
    <li class="topmenu"><a href="#">Main Menu</a>
      <ul style="visibility: hidden;">
          <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a></li>
          <li><a href="http://www.apple.com">Apple</a></li>
          <li><a href="http://www.microsoft.com">Microsoft</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>        
  </ul>
</div>
```

And the JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#jsddm > li').bind('mouseover', jsddm_open);
    $('#jsddm > li').bind('mouseout', jsddm_timer);

    // this work, but the submenus dont click
    $('.topmenu').bind('click', jsddm_open);
});
```

Tried different ways with no success

Working sample here:
http://jsfiddle.net/xjuZ4/

Comment: Your selectors appear to be the issue. `$('#jsddm > li')` will select all `li` descendants of `#jsddm`. `$('.topmenu')` selects only elements with that class, which, in your example, is only the "Main Menu".

What is the reason for the difference?

Comment: How about this? `$('#jsddm > li').bind('mouseover click', jsddm_open);`

Comment: @NADH: Same effect: submenus dont click

Comment: @N13: I've used a different selector so the bind don't catch the submenus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the click handler on the `<a>` tag. By putting the click handler on the top level `<li>` tag, you are intercepting any clicks on the child `<li>` tags as clicking on a child `<li>` tag is also clicking on the parent `<li>` tag.

You will want to add `e.stopPropagation();` to your click handler on the `<a>` tag to stop the hover out from being triggered.

You will also most likely want to use the JQuery method `.parent()` to find the `<li>` that the `<a>` lives in when the `click` method is triggered.

Updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xjuZ4/13/) with multiple drop down menus.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that the top menu is opened on mouseover and then closed when you click on it

Comment: @EduardoMolteni Fixed. Need to use `e.stopPropagation();`.

Comment: Now the submenus don't click and the menu disappears when navigating :(

Comment: @EduardoMolteni I updated my JSFiddle again to remove some code that could have been the issue. The apple and microsoft links are working for me in Chrome for both hovering and clicking.

Comment: The problem with the line you changed is when you have other top menu as seen in this update http://jsfiddle.net/xjuZ4/12/

Comment: @EduardoMolteni Tweaked the click method to pass along which `<li>` it is a child of.

Comment: I guess you forgot to Update the Fiddle. It's at /12 (the same as mine)

Comment: Works like a charm. +10 is too low for your effort. Many thanks!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10567/discussion-between-eduardo-molteni-and-brant-olsen)

Answer (score 0):

Delete `$('.topmenu').bind('click', jsddm_open);` in your javascript because you call links in tag `<a>`.